# Close the new opened tab - Python (Selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to close a new tab which I have opened with

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.google.com/');")
```

However, it is not working with the ways that I've tried. Which are:

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys('w').key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
```

And this one does work partially (it closes the driver tab which is **not** the goal):

```
driver.close
```

The goal is to close the **new freshly opened window/tab** in Chrome (Windows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the newly opened tab you first have to switch to that tab with

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

now you should close it with the

```
driver.close()
```

and then switch back to the main tab with

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```